# Red5 RTMPT not working

Tags: java, red5

I am trying to establish a connection to `Red5` server through `RTMPT`. I am using the `Red5` client jar `red5-client-1.0.jar`. While trying to connect, the following are successful.

`POST /open/1 HTTP/1.1`

`POST /send/DMPDQNDRFPCCV/1 HTTP/1.1`

`POST /idle/DMPDQNDRFPCCV/2 HTTP/1.1`

`POST /idle/DMPDQNDRFPCCV/3 HTTP/1.1`

After this, when the client sends

`POST /idle/DMPDQNDRFPCCV/4 HTTP/1.1`

I get the following error on the client side: 
`"Idle: unknown client session: DMPDQNDRFPCCV"`

What is the cause of this error? Is there any configuration to do in Red5. I have done all the necessary configurations to enable `RTMPT` as in http://gregoire.org/2009/01/28/rtmpt-and-red5/

Answer (score 1):

The unknown client message indicates that the session has been removed from the connection manager for some reason. I would suggest turning up the log levels and watching the console for more information.